# Unable to run tests in clojurescript with use-fixtures

Tags: testing, clojurescript

I have the following use-fixtures defined in my test file, along with a sample test to check whether use-fixtures is calling that anonymous function which is the value of the :before key.

```
(use-fixtures :each {:before (fn []
                               (prn "using fixtures")
                               )})
(deftest use-fixtures?
  (is (= 1 1)))
```

But running this test doesn't print "using fixtures" in the console or in the repl as expected. 
Why is this?

Comment: Where did you get the `:before` from? If you just pass the function (no map) that should work.

Comment: ClojureScript allows a hash map with `:before` and `:after` keys that identify 0-arity fixture functions (to call before and after the test). It's a difference between `cljs.test` and `clojure.test`.